# Alterar icone e display none/block

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, estou tentando fazer para que quando o botão seja clicado, altere a visibilidade de uma div e o icone mude.
Se eu remover a parte que remete aos icones, a visibilidade é alterada normalmente, porém, com o código inteiro, nada acontece.

funções:

```
function changeVisibility() {
        var display = document.getElementById("showup").style.display;

        if (document.getElementById("icon").classList.contains('fa fa-angle-down')){
            document.getElementById("icon").classList.toggle('fa fa-angle-up')
        }else if (document.getElementById("icon").classList.contains('fa fa-angle-up')){
            document.getElementById("icon").classList.toggle('fa fa-angle-down')
        }

        if(display == "none"){
            document.getElementById("showup").style.display = 'block';
        }else{
            document.getElementById("showup").style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

button:

```
<button onclick = "changeVisibility()" class = "btn btn-success btn-md">
            <span id = "icon" class = "fa fa-angle-down"></span>
        </button>
```

div que tem visibilidade alterada:

```
<div id = "showup" class = "form-row" style = "display: none">
            Code
    </div>
```

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identifiquei alguns problemas no seu código:

1. O ´classList.contains´ verifica apenas uma classe por vez, e você estava passando duas (`fa` e `fa-angle-down` ou `fa-angle-up`).
2. A lógica do toggle não estava correta.

Segue abaixo seu código com a lógica corrigida e algumas melhorias como jogar os elementos em uma variável para ficar mais otimizado e fácil de entender:

```js
function changeVisibility() {
  var $showup = document.getElementById("showup");
  var $icon = document.getElementById("icon");
  
  if ($icon.classList.contains('fa-angle-down')) {
    $icon.classList.add('fa-angle-up');
    $icon.classList.remove('fa-angle-down');
  } else if ($icon.classList.contains('fa-angle-up')) {
    $icon.classList.add('fa-angle-down');
    $icon.classList.remove('fa-angle-up');
  }

  if ($showup.style.display == "none") {
    $showup.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    $showup.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button onclick="changeVisibility()" class="btn btn-success btn-md">
  <span id="icon" class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
</button>

<div id="showup" class="form-row" style="display: none">
  Code
</div>
```

Comment: Entendi, vou testar quando chegar em casa. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado mesmo cara :)

Answer (score -2):

```js
function changeVisibility() {
  var $showup = document.getElementById("showup");
  var $icon = document.getElementById("icon");
  
  if ($icon.classList.contains('fa-angle-down')) {
    $icon.classList.add('fa-angle-up');
    $icon.classList.remove('fa-angle-down');
  } else if ($icon.classList.contains('fa-angle-up')) {
    $icon.classList.add('fa-angle-down');
    $icon.classList.remove('fa-angle-up');
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button onclick="changeVisibility()" class="btn btn-success btn-md">
  <span id="icon" class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).